# ImportError: cannot import name 'structural_similarity' error

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

In my image comparision code following: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/

While using
`from skimage.measure import structural_similarity as ssim`

and then 
`s = ssim(imageA, imageB)`

I am getting error:

> ```
> from skimage.measure import structural_similarity as ssim
> ```
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'structural_similarity'

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I found the solution. As this question is unique and not covered anywhere. So, posting the answer.

```
#from skimage.measure import structural_similarity as ssim
from skimage import measure
.
.
.
#s = ssim(imageA, imageB)
s = measure.compare_ssim(imageA, imageB)
```

Change commented line to uncommented line.

Answer (score 27):

Please check your skimage version.

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.compare_ssim

Changed in version 0.16: This function was renamed from `skimage.measure.compare_ssim` to `skimage.metrics.structural_similarity`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 26):

change import line to

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
```

This may work better than using compare_ssim since that is going to be deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I use next solution:

```
from skimage import metrics
metrics.structural_similarity(grayA, grayB, full=True)
```