# ImportError: cannot import name 'metrics' from 'skimage'

Tags: python, scikit-image

Here's the part that involves the use of `skimage` in the code:

```
from skimage import metrics

....

print(metrics.mean_squared_error(gray_frame, canny_img))
print(metrics.peak_signal_noise_ratio(gray_frame, canny_img))
```

Here's the error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>python cannyopencv2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cannyopencv2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from skimage import metrics
ImportError: cannot import name 'metrics' from 'skimage' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py)
```

Please help me get rid of it.

Comment: Please mention version of `skimage`

Comment: @BhavyaParikh its ```0.15.0```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install latest version of `skimage`  because that version does not have that module in it so use below command to upgrade it!

`pip install scikit-image -U`

or

`pip install scikit-image --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package first in order to use it.

`pip install scikit-image` or `pip3 install scikit-image`

[docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/install.html)

Comment: I think it is already installed as you can see from error traceback there is a folder created after installation

Comment: I think @BhavyaParikh might be on the right track here. You have the package installed, maybe it is the version issue. See similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178229/importerror-cannot-import-name-structural-similarity-error)

Comment: @yapancha exactly